# How to change the target size of images clicked on in Wordpress standard gallery

Tags: images, gallery

I want to use the standard Wordpress gallery without using other plugins and stick to the gallery shortcode. So, I know I can change the size of the thumbnails, that are shown in the gallery grid with for example `[gallery size="xyz" link="file"]`.

But I am not satisfied with Wordpress opening the biggest file then, when clicking on one of the thumbnails and I would like to have stated a different size, which I have created upfront by using `add_image_size( 'galleryimage', 900, 900 );` in my child's functions.php, of course.

Here is the code I am using for generating the galleries on static pages:

```
<?php

$people_attachments = new WP_Query( array(
'post_type' => 'attachment',
'post_status' => 'inherit',
'posts_per_page' => 0,
'category_name' => 'people', // note: use category SLUG
) );

$people_id_array = array();

if ( $people_attachments->have_posts() ) : while ( $people_attachments->have_posts() ) : $people_attachments->the_post();

$people_id_array[] = get_the_ID();

endwhile; endif;
// Important!
wp_reset_postdata();

$people_ids = implode( ',', $people_id_array );

echo do_shortcode( '[gallery link="file" columns="5" order="DESC" orderby="ID" include="' . $people_ids . '"]' );

?>
```

How do I add the target image size (size of linked image to be shown, when clicked)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across a solution for your `functions.php` from the following site that looks like it will do the trick. More detail on the implementation here:

- http://oikos.org.uk/2011/09/tech-notes-using-resized-images-in-wordpress-galleries-and-lightboxes/

Snippet below:

```
function oikos_get_attachment_link_filter( $content, $post_id, $size, $permalink ) {

// Only do this if we're getting the file URL
if (! $permalink) {
    // This returns an array of (url, width, height)
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, 'galleryimage' );
    $new_content = preg_replace('/href=\'(.*?)\'/', 'href=\'' . $image[0] . '\'', $content );
    return $new_content;
} else {
    return $content;
}
}

add_filter('wp_get_attachment_link', 'oikos_get_attachment_link_filter', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Some guys wrote, it does not work in newer Wordpress versions (since 3.7/3.8), but I have it now on 3.9 it looks fine. Thank you again. :)

Comment: Just another data point, worked for me in 4.6.1 without issues. Make sure to change `galleryimage` to your desired image size.